# Uninitialized first variable in a function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a strange problem with PHP and CodeIgniter. Here's the code of my file:

Skip this code and go to the second one I wrote. This remains here in case it might be useful.

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  require_once('utils.php');

  class FooterHeader {

    // Esta clase nos permite definir el footer y sus correspondientes menus
    var $utils;
    var $controller;

    var $TOPMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
    var $TOPMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
    var $TOPMENU_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
    var $TOPMENU_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
    var $TOPMENU_DESIGNER_NAMES;
    var $TOPMENU_DESIGNER_LINKS;

    // Side menu
    var $SIDEMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
    var $SIDEMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
    var $SIDEMENU_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
    var $SIDEMENU_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
    var $SIDEMENU_DESIGNER_NAMES;
    var $SIDEMENU_DESIGNER_LINKS;

    // Main menu
    var $MAINMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
    var $MAINMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
    var $MAINMENU_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
    var $MAINMENU_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
    var $MAINMENU_DESIGNER_NAMES;
    var $MAINMENU_DESIGNER_LINKS;

    function FooterHeader($controller) {
      $this->utils = new Utils();
      $this->controller = $controller;
      include_once 'defineMenus.php';
      configVars($this);
    }

    public function setDefaultHeader($situation) {
      $topMenuNames = array();
      $topMenulinks = array();
      $MainMenuNames = array ();
      $MainMenuLinks = array ();
      $SideMenuLinks = array ();
      $SideMenuNames = array ();

      // dependiendo del estado del usuario, mostramos cosas u otras
      if ($situation == NOT_LOGGED_IN) {
        $topMenuNames = $this->TOPMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
        $topMenuLinks = array ('users/login', 'users/register');
        $MainMenuNames = $this->MAINMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
        $MainMenuLinks = $this->MAINMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
        $SideMenuLinks = $this->SIDEMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
        $SideMenuNames = $this->SIDEMENU_NOT_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
      }
      else if ($situation == LOGED_IN) {
        $topMenuNames = $this->TOPMENU_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
        $topMenuLinks = $this->TOPMENU_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
        $MainMenuNames = $this->MAINMENU_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
        $MainMenuLinks = $this->MAINMENU_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
        $SideMenuLinks = $this->SIDEMENU_LOGGED_IN_NAMES;
        $SideMenuNames = $this->SIDEMENU_LOGGED_IN_LINKS;
      }
      else if ($situation == DESIGNER) {
        $topMenuNames = $this->TOPMENU_DESIGNER_NAMES;
        $topMenuLinks = $this->TOPMENU_DESIGNER_LINKS;
        $MainMenuNames = $this->MAINMENU_DESIGNER_NAMES;
        $MainMenuLinks = $this->MAINMENU_DESIGNER_LINKS;
        $SideMenuLinks = $this->SIDEMENU_DESIGNER_NAMES;
        $SideMenuNames = $this->SIDEMENU_DESIGNER_LINKS;
      }
      var_dump ($topMenuLinks);
      $this->setHeader ($topMenulinks, $topMenuNames, $MainMenuLinks, $MainMenuNames, $SideMenuLinks, $SideMenuNames);
    }

    public function setHeader ($topMenuLinks, $linkNames, $menus, $menusNames, $sideMenuLinks, $sideMenuNames) {
      var_dump ($topMenuLinks);
      $enlaces = $this->generateTopMenu ($linkNames, $topMenuLinks);
      $data['enlaces'] = $enlaces;
      $menus = $this->generateMenus ($menusNames, $menus);
      $data['menus'] = $menus;
      $sideMenus = $this->generateSideMenu ($sideMenuLinks, $sideMenuNames);
      $data['sideMenus'] = $sideMenus;

      $this->controller->load->helper('html');
      $this->controller->load->view('static/header.php', $data);
    }
  [...]
  }
```

Do not read it all. It's not necessary. Just look at the two `var_dump` calls. The first `var_dump` prints out:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'users/login' (length=11)
  1 => string 'users/register' (length=14)
```

The second one:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

I don't know why my variable is uninitialized. The rest of the variables are all OK.

Simplified the code:

```
<?php
  class FooterHeader {

    function FooterHeader($controller) {
      $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    public function setDefaultHeader($situation) {
      $topMenulinks = array();
      // dependiendo del estado del usuario, mostramos cosas u otras
      $topMenuLinks = array('users/login', 'users/register');
      var_dump($topMenuLinks);
      $this->setHeader($topMenulinks);
    }

    public function setHeader($topMenuLinks) {
      var_dump($topMenuLinks);
    }
  }
?>
```

But the problem is still occurring.

The code doing the calling is this:

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  require_once('utils/footerHeader.php');
  require_once('utils/defineMenus.php');

  class WelcomePage extends CI_Controller {

    var $fh;

    function WelcomePage() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->fh = new footerHeader($this);

      $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index()
    {
      // seteamos el header (el defecto)
      $this->fh->setDefaultHeader(NOT_LOGGED_IN);

      $this->load->view('subirDisenyoEjemplo.php');

      //$this->fh->setFooter();
    }
  }

  /* End of file welcomePage.php */
  /* Location: ./application/controllers/welcomePage.php */
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling these functions?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of PHP or CodeIgniter you are using, but be careful using `var` to declare your variables, as these variables will all be `public`. [More info in the user guide.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Could you please explain why you've written "do not read all, it's unnecessary" just after that when I HAVE read all?

Comment: Sorry, I'm stupid. I'm going to edit this.

Comment: @user1726613 It's a simple typo, as usually. Use [strict error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to avoid problems like that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out for capitalization:

```
var_dump($topMenuLinks);
$this->setHeader($topMenulinks);
```

$topMenu **L** inks vs. $topMenu **l** inks. I tried it on my server, and it immediately popped up as an uninitialized variable.

**Originally:**

The content of your array depends on the outcome of the `if` - `else if` construct. Only in this case

```
if ($situation == NOT_LOGGED_IN) {
```

will the array be assigned its value as in the first `var_dump()`. Otherwise, you will end up with an empty array because it is initialized as

```
$topMenulinks = array();
```

if you have any `situation` not covered by `LOGED_IN` or `DESIGNER`. Watch out for the missing  **G** in `LOGED_IN`.

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks! Just very stupid. I thing I'm going to sleep now... =)

Comment: My editor is highlighting same variables, but it dos not care about the capitalization... -_-

Comment: You're welcome, and good night. Have a look at Netbeans, it works nicely for me. Also, set your server to `E_STRICT` to get errors about this before it comes back to bite you :)

Answer (score 1):

Without the calling code it's kind of hard to determine, but I did find this:

```
$situation == LOGED_IN
$situation == LOGGED_IN
```

Comment: See my edit. I have simplified at max the code, but still happening. Second var_dump returns a empty array, but not the first one :((

Comment: check it out: `$topMenuLinks` and `$topMenulinks` Capitol L vs lowercase l.